# Clojure symbol evaluation error

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen, uberjar, clojure-1.3

So I currently have this code:

```
(ns contact-form.core
  (:gen-class))

(def foo "Hello World!")

(defn some-func [a-symbol]
  (println (str a-symbol "'s value is: " (eval a-symbol))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (some-func 'foo))
```

After I do `C-c C-k` in Emacs, I get the following output:

```
contact-form.core> (-main)
foo's value is: Hello World!
nil
```

But when I do `lein uberjar` and run the resulting jar file, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6235)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6469)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at contact_form.core$some_func.invoke(core.clj:7)
    at contact_form.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:10)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at contact_form.core.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6720)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6664)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6625)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6198)
    ... 10 more
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why does the uberjar not function exactly the same as the REPL?
2. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Why does uberjar function differently to the REPL?**

A cause of the error "NO_SOURCE_PATH" is that you are not presently in the namespace that defined 'foo.

To illustrate: if I evaluate your code in my REPL and execute it, it places me in the `contact-form.core` namespace as you would expect because `(ns contact-form.core)` is evaluated by the REPL, but if I switch to the `user` namespace and call `-main` I can produce the same error:

```
contact-form.core=> (-main)
foo's value is: Hello World!
nil
contact-form.core=> (ns user)
nil
user=> (contact-form.core/-main)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:120) 
user=>
```

So, by specifying your entry point to `main` for standalone uberjar execution (outside the REPL), it is equivalent to calling `(contact-form.core/-main)` from the default namespace in your jar which is `clojure.core`, because `(ns contact-form.core`) has not been evaluated. Result: `main` can be executed with a fully qualified (namespaced) path to the function, but none of the symbols from `contact-form.core` are available in the current default namespace.

**2. The fix**

The solution would be to explicitly switch to your namespace first.:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (use 'contact-form.core)
  (some-func 'foo))
```

Comment: `use` does much more than just switch namespaces.  I'd recommend ``(binding [*ns* (the-ns 'contact-form.core)] (some-func 'foo))``

Comment: @chouser Great! Consider me edified, sir!  :-)